# How do I use the Bootstrap toggle to create an event of true and false on my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-web-api

For example, when I (administrator) create a record and leave the Bootstrap toggle on, the record will be visible to the users. However, if I create a record and make the Bootstrap toggle off the record will be invisible to the users.

```
<script>
        //Using a function technique to create a JavaScript class, WebFormData
        function WebFormData(inSessionSynopsisName, inIsVisible) {
            this.sessionSynopsisName = inSessionSynopsisName;
            this.isVisible = inIsVisible;

        }

        $('#toggle-event').change(function () {


            var collectedIsVisible = $('#isVisibleInput').val();
        })

    $('#saveButton').on('click', function () {

    var collectedSessionSynopsisName = $('#sessionSynopsisNameInput').val();

    var webFormData = new WebFormData(collectedSessionSynopsisName, collectedIsVisible);
    var webFormDataInString = JSON.stringify(webFormData);
    $saveSessionSynopsisHandler = jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/API/SessionSynopses/',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                data: "'" + webFormDataInString + "'"
            })//end of ajax() call
            $saveSessionSynopsisHandler.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                new Noty({
                    text: data.message, type: 'success',
                    layout: 'center',
                    template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span>'
                }).show();
            });//end of saveCourseHandler.done();

            $saveSessionSynopsisHandler.fail(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(jqXHR);
                new Noty({
                    text: data.responseJSON.message, type: 'error',
                    layout: 'center',
                    template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span>'
                }).show();
            });//end of $saveCourseHandler.fail();
        });//end of $('#saveButton').on('click', function () {

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check befor onload your page the user:
if user admin change style to your button to turn it on
else if user not admin change style to your button to turn it off
to do some processing before loading a page you can use onunload please read this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp